# How to bring legacy applications, with different usernames, into an SSO solution?

Tags: single-sign-on

I have two web applications.  Today they both have their own way of authenticating users and storing their credentials.  Some of my users use both applications -but their usernames/passwords may be different in each application.

I would like to introduce a single-sign-on solution for these application so my users only need to worry about a single username/password.

**What is the best way to migrate these applications into an SSO solution?  Specifically, how do I securely associate a user in Application A with their respective user in Application B?**

For one user, since the usernames may be different in each application, I don't think I can run a script a 'merge them.'  I would prefer the users elect to merge their accounts and prove they own both accounts.  **Can OpenId Connect help with this problem?**  After authenticating with App A, I can ask if they would like to pair App B to their credentials in App A.  They would then be redirected to authenticated to App B.  If successful, it would redirect back to App A with their App B username in an OpenId Connect token.  The SSO solution would then store their App A and App B credentials together as a pair.  In the future, local app sessions with each application can still be creating using their legacy username but the user only deals with a single SSO username going forward.  Thoughts?   What are other approaches to solving this problem?

I'm not concerned about the cookie/cross-domain issues.  I'm most interested in how to reconcile the usernames across both systems.

Comment: SAML as an industry standard can solve this issue as you could 'auto-federate' the 2 different accounts.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr but does this only work if there is a common attribute on users in each app -like same email or username?  Because i don't have that with these apps.

Comment: if the accounts do not have anything in common you can not 'auto-federate' the accounts. Using 'SAML' account linking would allow the end-user to link/federate the accounts.